# Is it safe to pass a function or a class instance to the "target" argument of multiprocessing.Process without the risk of dense copying?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, multiprocessing, parameter-passing

I wonder is it possible to pass a function of another class, which has lots of imports and is pretty dense, to an instance of `multiprocessing.Process` as an argument? Note that I am going to run this code on a Unix-based machine and therefore `Process` will `fork` rather than `spawn`. Here's an example:

```
#class1.py
from class3 import Class3
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.class3Instance = Class3()

    def func1(self):
        self.class3Instance.func3()

#class3.py
import numpy as np
import pandas
import cv2 # OpenCV library
# there are many other things that I am importing here

class Class3(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func3(self):
        np.random.seed(1)
        print ('func3 changed the random seed')

#class2.py
import numpy as np
class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func2(self, funcInput):
        funcInput()

#main.py
from class1 import Class1
from class2 import Class2

class1Instance = Class1()
class2Instance = Class2()
from multiprocessing import Process

class2Process = Process(target=class2Instance.func2, kwargs={'funcInput': class1Instance.func1})
class2Process.start()
class2Process.join()
```

This example seems to work fine for such a small scale but I'm afraid `multiprocessing.Process` will not be able to `fork` things properly in this case and instead try to make a dense copy of the classes in the hierarchy. I do not want that to be the case. Is that a valid argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Process`, used in `fork` mode, will not need to pickle the bound method (which would require pickling the instance), so there will be minimal up front cost paid. There is no documented guarantee of this AFAICT, but CPython's implementation using fork doesn't do so, and there is no reason for them to do so, so I can't see them taking away that feature when there is nothing to be gained by it.

That said, the nature of CPython's reference counted design (with a cyclic garbage collector to handle the failures of reference counting) is such that the object header for all Python objects will be touched intermittently, which will cause any page containing a small object to get copied, so while the CPU work involved in actually performing a serialize/deserialize cycle won't occur, a long running `Process` will usually end up sharing few pages with the parent process.

Also note that `multiprocessing.Process`, in  `fork` mode, is the only time you benefit from this. `forkserver` and `spawn` launch methods don't get copy-on-write copies of parental pages, and therefore can't benefit, and `multiprocessing.Pool` methods like `apply`/`apply_async` and the various `map`-like functions *always* pickle both the function to be called and its arguments (because the worker processes don't know what tasks they'll be asked to run when they're forked, and the objects could have changed post-fork, so it always repickles them every time).

Comment: Based on your explanation it looks like I am going to be pretty much safe if I use `multiprocessing.Process` in `fork` mode. Right?

Comment: @Amir: Yep. You might eventually be paying the full RAM cost in both processes, but it won't be up-front, and the processing cost will be relatively cheap duplication of memory pages, not relatively expensive recomputation of the *contents* of those pages.

Comment: Sorry just to make it super clear: Does using `multiprocess.Process` in `fork` mode mean that Python will try to take off right where the `Process` instance is called and take as much stuff as possible right before `fork`ing takes place? This way it **will not** to redo the operations that are already done in previous lines of the code for other classes/instances before `Process` instance calls the `target` function. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. It's actually using the `fork(2)` system call, and then just assuming everything is set up as it needs to be. [The `_launch` method here is what it ultimately calls](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py#L67), and all that does is create a communications pipe, fork, then the [`Process` object's `_bootstrap` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L276) is called. The needs of after fork calls and the like do means it's slightly more costly than the raw system call, but it's not doing en masse recomputation.